# Skip prepare-commit-message git hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a prepare-commit-message set up that runs on every commit. I want to skip this hook on this one specific commit.

Using the --no-verify option is no help, since [the prepare-commit-message hook is not affected by that option](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg).

Is there any way for me to just skip the hook this one time without changing my configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You could (ab)use [`core.hooksPath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath):

```
git -c core.hookspath=/dev/null commit
```